# How to resize the button Icon according to the page resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an HTML page with 2 containers.
One of the containers, contains a transparent button with a question mark icon.
When ever I'm resizing the page, I would like the icon to be resized accordingly.

this is my div declaration in the HTML file:

```
<div class="container button">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-70">
        <a href="#kmeans" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-4x" aria-hidden="true" title="How does it work"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is how I set the container in the css:

```
section#analyze .container.button {
    border: 2px solid black; /*delete'*/
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 10%;
    width: 5%;
    display: none;
    height: 120%;
}
```

and this is how I set the button in the css:

```
section#analyze .container.button .btn-primary {
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline:none;
    font-size: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 20%;
    margin-top: 20%;
    position: initial;
}
```

What do I need to change in order for the ICON to be smaller or bigger when ever Im resizing the page itself?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the screen with and height properties in css. vw and vh: https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/